# How To access file outside the application

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to implement a small application using Spring MVC and JSP. In my application, I would like to display some images which are resided outside the application, lets say /home/images/sample.png. I know the how to access the images by configure the xml:

```
<!-- External css + js + images -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/**>
```

and in JSP

```
<img src=<c:url value="/resources/images/sample.png" />/>
```

I tried to apply the same logic to access the images in /home/images

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/**>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/image/**" location="file:/home/images/**" />
```

and in JSP, I tried to call it but no success:

```
<img src=<c:url value="sample.png" />/>
```

Comment: Check with <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/image/**" location="file:///home/images/**" />

Comment: I tried the code, it doesnt work. I also tried /home/images/sample.png in the JSP, but no luck as well

Comment: Can you post the relative path and absolute path as well and configuration you are giving?

Answer (score 0):

I think the JSP should be

```
<img src=<c:url value="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/image/sample.png" />/>
```

mvc:resources mapping should similarly

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="file:/C:/Users/home/directory_contain_image/"/>
```